# Não consigo criar layout dentro da requisição json

Tags: android, json, android-layout

Olá!

Em meu projeto, recebo alguns campos via JSON, tenho um layout vazio, e devo criar os elementos (textview, imageview, edittext...) conforme os dados recebidos do JSON.

O JSON estou recebendo corretamente, e fora dele, consigo criar qualquer elemento de layout programaticamente. O problema é que dentro da requisição do JSON, onde eu faço as verificações "if" para colocar elementos, a aplicação para de funcionar.

```
this.handler.get(nmForm, new HttpJsonObjectListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRequestCompleted(final JSONObject object, Integer httpStatus, CharSequence msg) {

            TextView t = new TextView(getBaseContext());
            t.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            t.setText("TextView");

            layout_form.addView(t);



            final JSONArray formFields = object.optJSONArray("formFields");

            for(int i = 0; i < formFields.length(); i++) {

                if(!tpRender.equals("HIDDEN")) {

                    Log.i("aanmLabel", nmLabel);
                    Log.i("tpRender", tpRender);
                    String qth = String.valueOf(qtHeight); 
                    Log.i("aaqtHeight", qth);
                    String qtw = String.valueOf(qtWidth); 
                    Log.i("aaqtWidth", qtw);

                    if(tpRender.equals("COMBO_BOX")) {
                        /*Spinner s2 = new Spinner(NewActivity.this);
                        s2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                        // e.setText("Button");
                        layout_form.addView(s2);*/

                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }, new HttpFailListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRequestCompleted(Exception e, Integer httpStatus, CharSequence msg) {
            Log.i("webview", "falhou ao obter json");
        }
    });
```

Coloquei apenas um textview como teste, e fora da verificação, mas não funciona.
Alguém me ajuda?

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver. Declarei programaticamente os layouts dentro do Handler, e dentro de

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
```